# MyEclipse + Maven + ActiveJDBC how to auto run instrumentation

Tags: java, database, maven, myeclipse, activejdbc

I am using MyEclipse + Maven and ActiveJDBC for my project.

I am deploying my project in exploded mode to a tomcat server from inside MyExclipse so I can profit from hot deploy during development. But everytime I change a DB class I have to manually instrument them. Is there a way to auto instrumented the classes? I already have the instrumentation plugin in my pom but that gets ignored.

If not I am thinking about moving to a different db framework. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

this page has an example  of bare bones instrumentation Ant script. You can adjust paths and wire this script to a menu action or button in Eclipse: http://code.google.com/p/activejdbc/wiki/Instrumentation#Bare_bones_Ant_script

Also, look at this thread, it has a link to a configured Eclipse project.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/activejdbc-group/eclipse/activejdbc-group/eaI1GNJAkVc/cTYxIlT1dLAJ

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my maven already does the instrumentation if I build my project. And I also have a bat to do the instrumentation manually. But thats not what I need for using eclispe/myeclipse exploded deployment on a server(tomcat). What do I need that instrumentation is executed on every hotdeploy from eclipse automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ActiveJDBC or advanced uses of maven but MyEclipse will not actually run a maven build during normal building or deployment. If you can get maven to do the deployment for you, then you can run a maven build from the context Run As menu, to do the work. Alternatively, you can add a builder from the Builders page (right click the project, select properties and go to the builders page), to run an ant build or an external program (e.g. to run maven externally, operating on the project in your workspace), every time a build is done (either manually or automatically) in MyEclipse.

Sorry this isn't a clear solution but, hopefully, it might give you some ideas to solve your problem.

Note that you may see a maven project builder on the Builders page but that doesn't run maven; it simply does some housekeeping associated with maven projects.